# 'Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable' when iterating?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

Does anyone know why the `self.indexCount` in the `ForEach` is giving the error `Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable` error? I can provide `aView` with `indexCount`, but it's not very convenient. I'm not changing indexCount. Is this a SwiftUI bug or intentional?

```
struct aView: View {
    let array: [[String]]
    lazy var indexCount: Int = array[0].count

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<self.indexCount, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("Hello World")
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's intentional. In SwiftUI, only `@State` variables can change. You can't use a `lazy var` like that. Replace it with a computed property:

```
var indexCount : Int { array[0].count }
```

That's better anyway, because it will always be correct: `indexCount` will always be the *current* size of `array[0]`), whereas *your* way, the value will freeze at whatever the `count` is the *first* time it is fetched.

Answer (score 3):

`lazy` always results in a mutation when the value is initialized.  Therefore, you cannot use it in a non-mutating context.

`body` is not `mutating` so you won't be able to use `lazy` there.  You get the same error with this minimal example:

```
struct LazyUser {
    lazy var something: Bool = { false } ()
}

func useSomething() {
    let notOk = LazyUser()
    var ok = LazyUser()
    _ = notOk.something // ERROR: Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'notOk' is a 'let' constant
    _ = ok.something
}
```

There is a thread about this [on the Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/allow-lazy-vars-on-immutable-structs/16417).