# Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried to use `ForEach()` to generate labels in a list

```
List {
    ForEach(objects) { obj in
        Label(obj.id, systemImage: obj.icon)
    }
}
```

The icon of each label is decided by its id so I use `lazy var` to define the struct

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    lazy var icon:String={
        // ...
    }
}
```

And create an array for each one

```
var objects = [
    Object(id:1),
    Object(id:2),
    // ...
]
```

But it throw an error like `Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'obj' is a 'let' constant`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60767041/1187415 to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects in `ForEach(objects) { obj in ... }` will be copied.
Copied value-type object (struct) is immutable, mean its properties could not be changed.

There is no need to use `lazy var icon:String = { }` because the `icon` value will be changed each time you call it (computation property), and it's not suitable for above immutable object logic.

Try to provide exact value before using in `ForEach`

```
struct MyObject: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let icon: String
}

var objects = [
    MyObject(id: 1, icon: "moonphase.waxing.crescent"),
    MyObject(id: 2, icon: "moonphase.waning.crescent"),
    // ...
]
```